# AngularJS Data Binding of chrome DateTime control not working After Update 24.0.1312.52

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs

Hope anyone else also observed this:-

We are using AngularJS 1.0 and using type="date" with  element to get Chrome's nice default datetime picker.
Everything was working fine till chrome updated itself recently to [24.0.1312.52]. Now If I change date using datetime picker, AngularJS data binding does not save it to bind json property of $scope.

If I change date via any keyboard key down, Data binding saves the date to property bind.

What could be the reason causing this problem.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We got help in angularJS google group:-

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/ycYzD3xRKS8

JSFeedle by Peter Bacon Darwin

http://jsfiddle.net/ZsRxj/

```
var module = angular.module('demoApp',[]);

module.directive('input', function () {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      if ( attrs.type="date" && ngModel ) {
        element.bind('change', function () {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(element.val());
          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed the same behavior and noticed that Sutikshan was on the right path.

HTML 5 [input date](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) requires the value to be in [RF 3339](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/references.html#refsRFC3339) format, therefore, we can adjust our AngularJS [input directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput) to format and parse the value accordingly.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('input', ['$filter',
function($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel || attrs.type != "date") return;

            // Using AngularJS built in date filter, convert our date to RFC 3339
            ngModel.$formatters = [function(value) {
                return value && angular.isDate(value)
                    ? $filter('date')(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                    : '';
            }];

            // Convert the string value to Date object.
            ngModel.$parsers = [function(value) {
                return value && angular.isString(value)
                    ? new Date(value)
                    : null;
            }];
        }
    };
}]);
```

The basics is that we ensure that the [NgModelController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) uses our $formatters and $parsers when updating the view value and model value, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Chrome doesn't fire `input` when you select a date via the picker.  A short-term hack is to forward `change` events (which Chrome *does* fire) to `input`; fortunately AngularJS doesn't use the event itself in the listener, so you don't need to worry about mapping event values or anything:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="date"]', null, function(){
  $(this).trigger('input');
});
```

A better solution would be to figure out why Chrome isn't firing `input`.

*Caveat: while there doesn't seem to be anywhere in the AngularJS code that would cause `change` to fire (thereby starting an infinite loop), and cursory testing implied the above works, the "better solution" would be a much better solution.*